# PHP exec() Not writing output file on IIS

Tags: php, exec

I am trying to run a script that results in different files being created via PHP exec command.  After writing the script I get no out put file.  So I wrote basic test code listed below.  I get the hostname to display in browser but no name.txt file.  This is running on IIS, I was thinking it was a permissions problems but I already added IIS guest account IUSR_hostname with write access to the folder in question, but still no txt file.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL); 
    exec("hostname > name.txt");
    echo exec("hostname");

?>
```

Comment: is `exec()` an allowed function? What happens if you use say `backtick` or `shell_exec()`

Answer (score 0):

Check if the user that PHP runs under have "X" permission on every directory of the file path. It will need it to access the file

If your file is: /path/to/test-in.txt You should have X permission on:

```
/path
/path/to
```

and read permission on /path/to/test-in.txt or through CPanel/ftp provide the write access to the file

Comment: Yes, I had set permissions along the path.  I found that I had to also add inheritable permissions.  After that it worked.
Site:  
http://coppermine-gallery.net/tutorial/permissions/iis.php